# different date format in different dlls

Tags: windows, datetime, culture

I am facing the datetime format issue where in one dll the datetime format is MM/dd/yyyy and when that value is passed to another dll there it expects the value to be in dd/MM/yyyy and hence cant perform any date conversion or comparison in the dll?

Is there a way to specify culture for entire solution so that all the dll follow the same culture?

And this happens only on some machines.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? What date time data type are you using?

Comment: am using .net 3.5 and datetime format i want is MM/dd/yyyy to be unform across the application.

Comment: If you're going to standardize on one date format, please consider [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)'s YYYY-mm-dd. Other programmers and users who have to deal with your data will thank you. dd/MM/yyyy is not great (because it's backwards from the way we write times) but MM/dd/yyyy is just a horrible idea.

Comment: Why are you passing dates between DLLs in string format?